# Script Copy down formatting: Not supported on a range with a filtered out row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script that copies the formatting of row 2 and pastes the formatting to all other rows. Works fine unless there is a filter being used that hides Row 2 then I get the following error message: This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered out row.

I would like the script to format all rows with or without the filter on and I would prefer to not disable the filter as whoever put it on may still need it. To be noted, the issue is just if row 2 is filtered.

[Sample Data & Test Workbook Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yVeeqhFxPKdX6dY3DKlOxGArzgl4fa8U9YQD9RVuu_4/edit?usp=sharing)

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Submissions");                                         // Team Member Sheet
  var master = Sheet1.getRange(2,1,1,Sheet1.getMaxColumns());
  var target = Sheet1.getRange(2,1,Sheet1.getMaxRows(),Sheet1.getMaxColumns());
  master.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for the community to understand, can you please share a sample sheet with your sample data and result. remove sensitive information.

Comment: Created with the link added above. Cheers.

Comment: Also edited the notes to clarify that the issue occurs when row 2 is filtered and not showing.

Comment: unfortunately, the link you  provided cannot be opened.

Comment: The link is not a proper link.  It actually looks like there is code within the link. I won't even try it.

Comment: My apologies, not sure what happened there but the link has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Replicating your concern, I would suggest you remove first the `filter` via apps script like this:

```
function Update_RowFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Submissions");  // Team Member Sheet

  var currentFilter = Sheet1.getFilter();
  currentFilter.remove();

  var master = Sheet1.getRange(2,1,1,Sheet1.getMaxColumns());
  var target = Sheet1.getRange(2,1,Sheet1.getMaxRows(),Sheet1.getMaxColumns());
  master.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
}
```

this will run the script without error but the drawback is , you have to manually re apply the filters since the `behavior of Google sheets filter is whenever you filter out certain rows, it won't treat them as part of the table` that's why you are getting that error message.

Otherwise, you might want to opt for another alternative approach.

*Ref: [Remove a filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#remove-a-filter)*